# Does apt-get install package from ppa first and then official repository?

Tags: apt, ppa

I want to get the most recent version of nodejs installed, so I add the `ppa:chris-lea/node.js` .

but does it mean when I run `apt-get install nodejs`, it will install the package from the ppa instead of the official repository???

How does apt-get determine from which source to install a package???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `apt-get` searches all available package sources and installs the package with the highest version number.

```
apt-cache policy nodejs
```

shows you all packages for `nodejs` with their versions from your package sources and tells you which one it would install ("`Candidate`").

There are some weays to change this behaviour, see for example [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)